# Is it possible to create a custom editor for Wordpress Custom Post Types?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to mimic something similar to Visual Composer/WPBakery by creating a custom page builder in WordPress. I am not sure how VC manages to take over the default WordPress editor. Is it possible to completely replace this editor like what VC seems to be doing or are they just adding to the editor and making it seem like it is different. I have tried reviewing the source code but am no expert in PHP and it's hard for me to understand how they are doing it. I would like to create my own custom post type and have the custom editor only apply to my custom post type. Any help/advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Creating a wysiwyg editor isn't an easy task.

Comment: @Second2None I have already created an editor with react and would just like to render it in place of the default editor.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what's not working? You should edit your question with some code you have tried, and explain what isn't working.

Comment: @Second2None I am more just wondering if this is even possible. I have looked into the wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $settings = array() ); function built into WordPress which I theorize that maybe I would be able to render my React Component into the $content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that this is completely possible through page templates. David, the author of [this article](https://shellcreeper.com/wp-page-builder-plugin-from-scratch/) provides an awesome solution of how to accomplish this.